# How to get percentage of object in Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, percentage

I have stream of integers and I try to find percentage of 1's over all. I cannot find the solution.

```
connections
        .flatMap(co -> co.stops().stream())
        .map(ts -> ts.kind() == kind ? 1.0 : 0.0)
```

I don't want to share class types and make things complicated. I just want to calculate percentage.

Comment: For me I would want to avoid fiddling with constants 0.0 and 1.0. Start by `Map<Boolean, Long> partitioned = connections .flatMap(co -> co.stops().stream()) .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(ts -> ts.kind() == kind, Collectors.counting()));`. Then calculate the percentage from the two obtained counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `map`, use [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to get an `IntStream`, and then [`average()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--) will get you the percentage you want:

```
.mapToInt(ts -> ts.kind() == kind ? 1 : 0).average()
```

This gives you an `OptionalDouble`, which will be empty if the stream is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the summary statistics of a `DoubleStream`:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = connections.flatMap(co -> co.stops().stream())
        .mapToDouble(ts -> ts.kind() == kind ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        .summaryStatistics();
double percentage = 100 * stats.getSum() / stats.getCount();
// or
double percentage2 = 100 * stats.getAverage()
```

Comment: On one hand the `getAverage` method is nice, on the other hand for most purposes it’s probably a drawback that it returns 0.0 from an empty stream.